React Native OAuth2 Backend for Frontend With Spring Cloud Gateway BFF
Hello I am using learning about OAuth.  I have a react native app, and I want to connect it to my Java Spring backend, with OAuth.  I used this tutorial to add OAuth to my Java backend: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2, and now I want to connect my react native app, but from what I understand I need a token.
How can I sign in users with the app?  I can't find any examples that allow me to use this backend.
I have tried authenticating through the browser and redirecting, but even if I manage to sign in no other requests work.

Requests to Spring clients with oauth2Login are authorized with session cookies, not with Bearer tokens. As session cookies are credentials that system browsers won't share with other applications, you'll have to be careful with the user agent with which your mobile device sends the authorization code to the Spring backend after it receives it from the authorization server.
If you intercept the response from the authorization server containing the authorization code using an Android App Link or iOS Smart Link, then you can provide this code to your Spring backend with the app HTTP client instead of the system browser.
Detailed flow:

Configure the BFF to set the status of response to authorization requests with something in the 2xx range instead of 302 (necessary for the next step to be possible). This is easy with a starter of mine, with usage for an OAuth2 BFF described in the Baeldung article you linked. The article is focused on SPAs for which changing the status of the response to the RP-Initiated Logout is enough, but there is another configuration property to modify the authorization request response status too.
Send a GET request to the BFF "login" endpoint (the one initiating authorization code flow and returning a redirection to the authorization server) with the internal app HTTP client
Save the session cookie contained in the response in a very safe place. If a malicious program reads it, user identity can be stolen and requests sent on his behalf! I save session and CSRF cookies in memory.
Follow to the authorization server using the URI in the Location header of the response above. This should be done with the system browser, not the app HTTP client (the authorization server might need to display the login forms or use cookies for SSO).
If deep linking is correctly configured (Android App link or iOS Smart Link), the response from the authorization server with the authorization code should land in the app. Read this URI containing the authorization code and follow it using the app HTTP client, attaching the session cookie saved at step 3.

If the code is valid, and because the user-agent providing the code and session cookies are those from the login initiation, the BFF will exchange the code for tokens on the authorization server, save these tokens in session and the following app HTTP client requests with the same session cookie will be authorized.
If the redirection from the authorization server with the authorization code is followed with the system browser (because of missing or broken deep linking configuration) the authorized session on the Spring backend will be the system browser session, and the REST request sent by your app won't have the context of this authorized session.
Also, mobile apps internal HTTP clients usually don't handle cookies transparently like browsers do. So, you'll need something to store the session and CSRF cookies and correctly attach them to the requests (only to requests sent to your Spring backend, and for the CSRF token, only with POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE requests). For security reasons, I store these cookies in memory only. Writing the code to handle these cookies isn't much work.
Last, mobile apps can't access dev machine using localhost which, of course, loops to the mobile device. So, we should make sure that the hostname used for the Issuer Identifier - issuer-uri in Spring conf, hostname in Keycloak conf, issuer in /.well-known/openid-configuration, etc. - is known on the mobile device and points to the host on which the authorization server runs. Also, the device browser will probably complain if SSL is not used or if the OS doesn't know about the certificate root authority. You can hack with a self signed certificate and a local DNS, but it's probably easier to deploy a Keycloak instance in the cloud (if you have one already) or to use a test / demo / trial from a cloud provider like Auth0, Amazon Cognito, Microsoft Entra ID (with special care to use V2 tokens), etc.

I'm sorry it's been a while since I tried keycloak configuration.  I can't access the login page from my phone or an emulator.  Do I need to change the keycloak configuration?

I see I'm sure you're very busy.  Thanks for responding.  I believe authentication-entry-point is the property, but I'm not sure what to change it to.  I tried setting it to unauthorized to see if it would give me a 401, but I still get a 302.

In Spring Security, authentication-entry-point is to handle unauthorized requests to protected resources. On a REST API this should be configured to return 401 , but this is not the point here. What you want to change is the status of the 1st request in the authorization code flow. In spring-addons-starter-oidc, the property for that is pre-authorization-code (which you might set for instance to OK)

I have tried looking at the github, but I'm not sure where to find information on the property I need to change.  I have tried changing the bff yml.  I have placed the authentication-entry-point under com:c4-soft:springaddons:oidc and I set it to ok.  I am still getting a 302 and I can't see the response, because of the redirect.  Could you tell me where the property needs to be placed, and where to find the information for this property?

Properties are decorated with Javadoc, so, your IDE should help with application.yml auto-completion. If it doesn't, use another one (Eclipse STS or VS code for instance). You can also refer to the starter documentation which contains this info.

I think you need to set up authorization server if you haven't set up any(https://auth0.com/intro-to-iam/what-is-oauth-2) then
from your front end(react native app) need to get an authorization code and use that code to get a refresh token and access token.
here ex : https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angular

That makes sense let me try that.

No, that doesn't make sense. The all point of the OAuth2 BFF pattern is that the OAuth2 client (what tokens are issued to) is on the server, not on the end-user device.

@ch4mp that's mainly why I'm asking the question.  All of the solutions I look at include tokens.  I'm do I need to log in on a web browser and use the cookies?
